# QML form layout

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

I use QML for UI in my app and now I want to build some form.
This is a code:

```js
Window {
    width: 400
    height: 600
    flags: Qt.Dialog
    modality: Qt.ApplicationModal

    GridLayout {
        id: mainLayout
        columns: 2
        rowSpacing: 5
        columnSpacing: 5
        anchors {
            top: parent.top;
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }

        Label { text: "field1" }
        TextField { id: field1; }

        Label { text: "field2"}
        TextField { id: field2 }
    }
}
```

How can I set width for the `TextField`s? Most of them have to fit all the space in the right column.

That how it looks now:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use attached properties of items placed inside `GridLayout` (see [official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html#details)), so changes in your code will look like:

```
...
Label { text: "field1" }
TextField { id: field1; Layout.fillWidth: true;}

Label { text: "field2"}
TextField { id: field2; Layout.fillWidth: true;}
...
```

Comment: You are welcome☺ take a look at other properties, it may be also helpful.